# Django STATIC_URL value not recognized in production

Tags: django, apache, mod-wsgi

I'm trying to deploy my Django app onto production with Apache+mod_wsgi, but running into troubles withs static files. For some reason `{{ STATIC_URL }}` is not being recognized by my templates in production. In development my static files have the URL:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/static/js/myfile.js"></script>
```

but in production the URL is:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/myfile.js"></script>
```

When I try to print out `{{STATIC_URL}}` it is blank in production. What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: First of all it is recommended to start the string for `STATIC_URL` setting with a leading slash: `/static/` instead of `static/`. This will probably not fix your problem though. What is written for `STATIC_URL` in your `settings.py`? Can you check on production with `python manage.py shell` -> `from django.conf import settings` -> `print settings.STATIC_URL`. What does it say?

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I just checked and I actually do have a leading slash in my settings.py for `/static/`. Sorry I just typed the code out of memory. By 'production' I just meant my local Apache + mod-wsgi installation. When I do the shell command you requested, I got `/static/` as expected. To clarify, my dev and production right now are on the same machine. Dev is using `manage.py runserver` and production is using Apache + mod-wsgi. Thanks!

Comment: Ok, interesting. Did you put `'django.core.context_processors.static'` to your `TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS` setting? This makes `{{STATIC_URL}}` available in your templates when rendered with `RequestContext` in your views. Though if it shows it on dev, but not on production I guess you did. Right now I don"t have another exmplaination for this.

Comment: Yes I do have that line in my context processor. Thanks for your help :) Anyone else have any other ideas?

Comment: Have you restarted the server or `touch` the wsgi file?  Can't think of much else based on these comments.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes I have done both many many times...

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I'm running into the same issue with my local dev server

python manage.py runserver
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Answer (score 6):

Just came across this trying to solve this problem myself. The key step for me was that my views were being passed a `Context` rather than a [`RequestContext`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#django.template.RequestContext) object. To solve this, where I was using the `render_to_response` method, I had to provide the following third parameter:

```
context_instance=RequestContext(request)
```

Your problem was obviously solved, but this is just in case someone else runs into the same issue.

Comment: Do you know why exactly this is? On the dev server I wasn't seeing it, only in production. What is it about django.core.context_processors.static that behaves different with Apache + mod_wsgi?

Answer (score 1):

Is mod_wsgi using the same python as your shell? And the same PYTHONPATH?

I suggest to try another web server, just to know if it's a mod_wsgi problem or it's a problem with your setup/environment. Gunicorn is very easy to set up. To use it:

- `pip install gunicorn`
- add `gunicorn` to your INSTALLED_APPS
- run the production server with `./manage.py run_gunicorn`

Comment: Ill try that. Thanks. I eventually just restarted my whole damn machine and it fixed it.

Comment: probably the PYTHONPATH as seen by mod_wsgi was not up-to-date.